# How to run the same java program with different command line arguments from a file

Tags: java, batch-file, arguments, command-line-arguments

I want to run a java program `SampleProgram.java` 10 times with different parameters. I checked running the java program from .bat file. My question is that is it possible to run the same program `SampleProgram`multiple times like the following :

```
java -jar SampleProgram.jar argument1 argument2
java -jar SampleProgram.jar argument3 argument4
java -jar SampleProgram.jar argument5 argument6
```

Will writing the above lines in a batch file, testRun.bat and running runTest.bat run the java programs with different arguments?

Comment: Of course it would. Also, why can't you just try this out yourself?

Comment: I was doing a basic research on if this is possible. And I didn't find much useful links. So I thought of asking the question.

Comment: Ok, but whats stopping you just running it yourself and finding out? It takes longer to type out your question than it does to try it yourself

Comment: Yeah. I could have.

Answer (score 2):

You probably need to launch them with `start /B` to launch them in background otherwise your batch will launch them sequentially instead of launching them in parallel. So try this:

```
start /B java -jar SampleProgram.jar argument1 argument2
start /B java -jar SampleProgram.jar argument3 argument4
start /B java -jar SampleProgram.jar argument5 argument6
```

As it is done in [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/345605).